# Would large-scale, landowning farmers be able to run family farms?

Tags: internal-consistency, agriculture

Several thousand large scale farmers and their families end up as refugees after a decolonization war. They end up destitute with their land nationalized and their assets seized.

The country that gives them  asylum, gives each family a little land and minimal capital (seeds, basic tools) in order for them provide for their own sustenance. The host country is quite poor itself, but has some land to spare. However the government is, though not socialist, against the big business and especially against hired labor.

Would the former large farmers families be able to survive running a family farm without hired labor starting with only minimal capital?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you mean the farmers are large (as in big people) or they have large farms. Could you clarify by rewording?

Comment: @LioElbammalf 'large scale farmers' seems pretty clear.

Comment: Hello, interesting question. However, we need more information to be able to answer it, such as crop types, climate differences, and technology level. For example, the owners of a slave plantation would probably not be able to run a family farm, not least because they would personally not have the experience to do so. Farmers from a temperate climate would have a difficult time trying to farm in the tropics. On the other hand, wealthy landowning peasants that fled Germany in 1870, or the Ukraine in 1917 and settled in Nebraska would (and did) do just fine. For now, this question is too broad.

Comment: And what do you mean by "family farm"? The picture you have in your head (red barn, a cow, and a flock of chickens) hasn't ever really been "A Thing."

Comment: Relative historic period is critical to answering this. For example, are they 19th Century nobility with tenant farmers or modern high tech farmers.

Comment: "The government is [...] not socialist, against the big business and especially against hired labor" -- doesn't this make it either a _feudal_ or a _slave holding_ country by process of elimination?

Comment: @AlexP I imagine that it is the kind of government that imagines itself to be the Jeffersonian antebellum US or Republican Rome, where sturdy yeoman family farmers are called up to man the militia/legions in defense of God(s) and country. Although, your point is pretty valid since both these small-farm utopias were also slave-holders.

Comment: Low tech farming isn't that difficult given the tools and plants and willingness to work

Comment: @Separatrix 1960s-1970s

Comment: @kingledion I was thinking of something like  white large scale farmers in Africa. I don't know enough about agriculture to specify more.

Comment: @NaamNaamSaddam, if you edit the requested information into the question it should be reopened to get you more answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel that some would be able to manage, but of course there was would be serious challenges for each family. Large-scale farmers probably at least have an idea of how farming works, but rely heavily on equipment, hired labor, and large amounts of capital to run their farms. It's more business management than farming.

If you take all of that away and hand them a hoe, they could probably plant a garden, but might not be capable of maintaining it or turning any kind of profit. They would make mistakes that normally their mid-level managers would have known better than to make. Perhaps they would over estimate their potential yield based on prior experience, but not realize how much work it will be for their family to plant and harvest.